# How to execute subclass's inherited initialize method after construction?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, constructor, initialization

Consider the following code:

```
public abstract class Command {

    public Command() {
        configure();
    }

    public void configure() {
    }

}


public abstract class ComplexCommand extends Command {

    private ArrayList<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        System.out.println(commands);
    }

}
```

The `configure()` method is intended to be implemented by subclasses of either Command or ComplexCommand in order to modify attributes of the commands, so the intended functionality is to execute the `configure()` method in the implementation subclass after it has been constructed (the commands variable has been initialized). However, calling `new ComplexCommand()` in this example will result in `null` being printed out to the console. Correct me if I'm wrong but it that appears to be because the implied `super()` in the subclass constructor is executed before the subclass fields are initialized.

Here is an example of how these classes are used:

```
public class MyTestCommand extends Command {

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        setUsage("Usage: /test <target>");
        setDescription("This is a test command");
    }

}
```

Playing around with this, I did figure out one way to get around the problem, but I'm wondering if anyone has a better solution. My fix was to override the parent constructor by creating one which allows enabling/disabling executing `configure()` from the parent and then running it from the child instead.

```
public abstract class Command {

    public void configure() {
    }

    public Command() {
        configure();
    }

    protected Command(boolean configure) {
        if (configure) {
            configure();
        }
    }

}

public abstract class ComplexCommand extends Command {

    private ArrayList<String> commands = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        System.out.println(commands);
    }

    public ComplexCommand() {
        super(false);
        configure();
    }

}
```

In this example `configure()` correctly runs after the subclass's fields have been initialized and `[]` is displayed. Regardless, it still seems pretty hacky and probably confusing at first. Is there a better way to do this besides what I have done?

Comment: What not you just remove `configure();` from the constructor of the superclass?

Comment: @Yahya I want users to be able to implement and use configure() for either class for different use-cases.

Comment: Seeing as your Command class is abstract, wouldn't it make sense for the method configure to be abstract too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This whole idea is flawed in my opinion since you are just using the configure method as a substitute for a subconstructor. It's not usefull in any way.

Why do you need configure in the first place? So subclasses can override it you say. But they already can override the constructor so what's the point?

```
public abstract class Command {   

    public Command() {
        // Do things to initialize Command
    }    
}

public abstract class ComplexCommand extends Command {

    private ArrayList<String> commands;

    public ComplexCommand() {
        super();
        // Do things to initialize ComplexCommand
        this.commands = new ArrayList<>();
        System.out.println(this.commands);
    }    
}

public class MyTestCommand extends Command {

    public MyTestCommand() {
        super();
        setUsage("Usage: /test <target>");
        setDescription("This is a test command");
    }    
}
```

Comment: This works for what I'm doing, thanks. I got too caught up in removing the constructor while I was refactoring the code.

Comment: @Yahya you just suggested removing configure() from the constructor of the super class. If I had done that, implementations using Command would not have their configure methods ever executed.

Comment: @kmecpp Are ya kidding me?! Look at the accepted answer above. Removing `configure()` from the superclass constructor will achieve the exact same thing! Your question wasn't even clear of what you wanna achieve! The above answer is just a classic ordinary way of implementing the inheritance in OOP. That's unbelievable that you cannot figure out that you wanna just the basics for your program.
I spent hours today trying achieving that using `Reflection`. And all you meant in the end a simple basic implementation of inheritance!

Comment: @Yahya Haha sorry. Your comment wasn't clear either though. If I were to just have removed configure() from the superclass constructor it wouldn't have worked. You never said to not use the method entirely. I chose this answer because it happened to work for what I was trying to accomplish despite altering the style of the API (using the constructor instead of a separate method). If you can find a better solution to my original question which keeps the configure() method I will happily change my accepted answer :)